# PHP header and output buffering not working

Tags: php, header

I'm confused about how output buffering works with the PHP header function.

Here is my code:

```
session_start();

header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/database.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/functions.php');

$db = new Database();
$db->open_connection(); // to database
$query = 'SELECT * FROM english WHERE id = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['dealerID']);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
ob_start();
ob_flush();
header('http://www.domain.com/channel-partners/en/index.php?dealerID=' . $row['id'] . '&location=' . $row['location_url'] . '&name=' . $row['name_url']);   
ob_end_flush();
```

This doesn't work.  I get the "headers already sent" error.  I know that I can't have any output before I call the header command, but I thought if I used ob_start() I could have output before the command is called.  Obviously I am mistaken, but I don't know how to rectify this code so that I can have the session_start() where it needs to be, open a connection to my database and then call the redirect.  Can someone help out?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any blank space before your <?php open tag? If so, it is being sent as output to the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the call to `ob_flush()`.  This sends output to the response and prevents you from setting any more headers.

Also, you should encode your query string parameters:

```
header('http://www.domain.com/channel-partners/en/index.php?dealerID=' . urlencode($row['id']) . '&location=' . urlencode($row['location_url']) . '&name=' . urlencode($row['name_url']));
```

Or better yet, use the [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) function:

```
$params = array("dealerID"=>$row['id'], "location"=>row['location_url'], "name"=>$row['name_url']);
header('http://www.domain.com/channel-partners/en/index.php?' . http_build_query($params));
```

**EDIT:**

One more thing.  You're not escaping the dealerID properly in your query string.  The `mysql_real_escape_string()` function is only useful for SQL strings.  It is not useful for numeric values.  Use the [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) function to check to make sure that the dealerID parameter is a number:

```
$dealerID = $_GET['dealerID'];
if (!ctype_digit($dealerID)){
  die('Invalid value for "dealerID" parameter.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can't have any output before I call the header command, but I thought if I used ob_start() I could have output before the command is called.

You can, but you're calling `ob_flush()` prior to your header call, which sends output to the browser. Why? Take out the `ob_flush()` call and it should work exactly as intended.

Comment: Then you're likely doing something wrong in the include files too.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out where the headers were sent with:

```
if (headers_sent($file, $line)) { 
   echo "Headers were sent at file=$file, line=$line";
}
```

This should allow you to debug the problem

Comment: The error message already includes the file and line, doesn't it?

Comment: What is at the file/line where you sent the output? I suspect it's a BOM or blank line in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put ob_start(); right at the top of your script.